# Python regex with an OR condition

Tags: python, regex

I have created my code using beautiful soup, got my url page loops working and moved my item into panda dataframe.

Problem is that if my beautiful soup object doesn't pick up a value my arrays get messed up.

I'm using regex to find my items in beauitfulsoup.

The clause thats messing me is the following where i search for item with width 10% and 4 characters.

```
for item in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^\d{4}$')):
```

However I would like to add another condition to the regex to pick up items that have 4 characters **OR** contain charachter '£'

I have tried the following but it only produces a syntax error.

```
for item in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^\d{4}$') or string=re.compile(r'^(£)')):
```

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the search for `£` into your existing regex:

```
for item in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^(\d{4}|.*£.*)$')):
```

I've assumed there can be other characters than `£` in the string, if that is not the case (it is simply `£`) then remove the `.*` parts of the alternation i.e.

```
for item in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^(\d{4}|£)$')):
```

Answer (score 1):

First, why the syntax error:

```
soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^\d{4}$') or string=re.compile(r'^(£)'))
```

You've effectively done

```
func(arg1, arg2, arg3=something or arg3=somethingelse)
```

Your `or` is not contained within either argument that you are passing, you're inserting it between specifying of 2 named args, where a comma would usually go. This is wrong because,

1. Python doesn't support this syntax, because...
2. Passing `something` or `somethingelse` simultaneously as the same argument to a function call doesn't make sense in general, because...
3. What you're actually trying to do (to my understanding), is get the `find_all` function body itself to incorporate your desired `or` logic, which has nothing to do with the argument evaluation step.

When in doubt, read the docs. Here's what beautifulsoup says about [the `string` argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) of `find_all`

> With string you can search for strings instead of tags ... you can pass in a string, a regular expression, a list, a function, or the value True

So we can pass a regex to `string`, which of course you were already doing. So back on track here, can we make a regex that checks the condition you described? Yes! Using grouping and the `|` (or operator)

`(^\d{4}$)|(^.*£.*$)`
This regex will match anything this is

- 4 digit characters from the start to end

  - or
- Anything containing a `£` character

Here's an example of it in action https://regex101.com/r/cl9KW7/4